# Spurious high disk IOrate alerts from remote server

Tags: ubuntu, performance, disk-utility, utilization

I have a server running on linode. The server is a headless Ubuntu 10.0.4 64 bit installation.

I have recently started getting high disk I/O alerts from the server. As far as I know, nothing much has changed on the server.

Is there a *nix utility that I can run on the server to either monitoring and log, or perhaps analyze an existing log in order to find out which process(es) are "trashing" the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some ideas:

IOtop: http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/

Atop: http://www.atoptool.nl/

Nmon: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-analyze_aix/

Collectl: http://collectl.sourceforge.net/Process.html